# recurrence function time complexity with if-else statement

Tags: time-complexity

I am having some trouble solving the time complexity of below function.

```
pubilc static long powerN(long x, int n){
      if(n==0) return 1;
      if(n%2 == 0){
            long a = powerN(x, n/2);
            return a*a;
      }
      else {
            long a = powerN(x, (n-1)/2);
            return a*a;
      }

}
```

I've learned that if there is an if statement, we take greater complexity of then/else statement.

In above example, both conditional statement's time complexity is same, so I concluded in this way.

Assume, function powerN be T(n),

```
T(n) = T(n/2) + k (k is the overhead)
```

so I concluded T(n)'s time complexity is `O(logn).`

But I am still wondering if my assumptions is right. Thank you.

Comment: Your analysis is correct. You can use this method to bound from above, as selecting the complexity essentially even bounds running both branches.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your assumption is basically correct, at least in this case.

In general you need to check the meaning of the if-else statement and how often it is triggered. If one if-else branch is called as often as the other (or better to say complexity-like as often as other - calling it i.e. 10 times more still does not change complexity. Calling if-branch `k times` more than else-branch if `k` is constant is fine. Calling it i.e. `log n` times more does affect complexity).

Just imagine the if statement would be as this:

```
public static long powerN(long x, int n){
      if(n==0) return 1;
      if(n < 100){
            long a = powerN(x, n-1);
            return a*a;
      }
      else {
            long a = powerN(x, (n-1)/2);
            return a*a;
      }

}
```

Then basically the if-branch is running in constant time for n < 100 and you should ignore it.

Or imagine this one: This would run with `T(n/2)` up to `n = log(N)` and then `T(n-1)` for `log(N)` time. Then you simply cannot just take "what is inside" if-else branch and choose the bigger one.

```
long initialN = 10000;
long intialX = 500;
powerN(initialX, initialN);

public static long powerN(long x, int n){
      if(n==0) return 1;
      if(n > log(initialN) ){
            long a = powerN(x, n/2);
            return a*a;
      }
      else {
            long a = powerN(x, n-1);
            return a*a;
      }

}
```